# bold and color with unix's more

Tags: unix, pipe

I pipe compiler output into `more` (to avoid getting pages upon pages of warnings when I really only want to know the first few), but this doesn't preserve bold and color. Is there a way to preserve these with more? (for whatever reason on my mac `man more` gives the man page for `less`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"because less is more" ;)

Try `more -R`.

Comment: okay that gives me some more help. but there seems to be no solution

Comment: The `-R` flag should pass bold/color codes, but some programs don't output those codes when they see they are connected to a program (like `more`) instead of a terminal. In that case, they just don't generate those codes.